# IE9 ignoring inline-block property

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

IE9 completely ignores inline-block property. All other browsers including IE8 works fine.
I'm clueless.

In case anyone asks about DOCTYPE I'm using it and it looks like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

but I've tried `<"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`

as well with the same result

[website](http://www.webintelligence.ie)

Comment: Where is the `inline-block` on that website, and what seems to be wrong with it?

Comment: it's nested couple of levels in page>content  div tag with id "item-index"

Comment: try the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: It's really hard to see what you're trying to achieve by looking at the source of a whole website. Can you paste the specific code you're looking at, what you're trying to achieve, and what it's doing in IE9?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by having a single inline-block element...

Comment: thanks for the effort, but it is really hard to paste the code when I have no clue what is wrong. There Are four columns on website and they all should be in centre. They are wrapped in wrapper which has inline-block property. Chrome,FF, IE8 - all render it just fine. in IE9 "inline-block" is ignored and wrapper behaves like "block"

Comment: Good question Kolink but I would rather discuss why it doesn't work in IE9...

Comment: I made my rooter working and tried that on localhost and surprise. Identical page works on localhost in IE9 like a charm. The same thing pulled from server and IE9 goes into quirks mode. any idea?